# Ruby-only web server (for embedded device)?

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a very limited environment and need a ruby (based) web server; currently I'm using Webrick but; I'm concerned about its oldness and lack of documentation. I can't install anything that requires building/compiling c/header files (like Mongrel or Thin). Are there any other alternatives for me?

edit: Upon request: The device I'm working with is an intelligent RFID reader, with an embedded linux arm based computer on-board. The only api/language manufacturer allows and provides (w/o getting out of license terms) is ruby, and they give no-support for installing extra-stuff and they have customized the kernel in device to make installing/compiling anything as hard as possible. That is why I can only use Webrick atm since; it is included in standard ruby distribution. I can use extra ruby stuff if they're just .rb lib files that is I can easily just include them in my code, but anything that requires compiling is a no-no.
Also, this system does not have gem.

Comment: What environment are you working in that is so limited? A shared server space?

Comment: Can you tell us OS, Distro, rails version? It will help us to give you a better answer.

Comment: Mb i wrong understand, but mb u need restful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is no. The best advice I can give you is to dig into Webrick and understand how it works. Then the lack of documentation and oldness is less of a problem.

But if Webrick truly doesn't suits your needs you *could* knock up your own using Ruby's TCPServer library and Rack.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure but does doing a

```
gem install thin
```

requires you to compile anything?

Disregarding that one, I think you have quite a issue. Maybe downloading some .deb/.rpm with the server compiled?

Answer (score 0):

have you considered [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) ?

Comment: Passenger works well, but the default install wants to custom-compile for the local Apache installation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just target Rack, and then you can easily try several web servers until you find one that works for your environment.  Plus, that gives you a lot more flexibility.  Any particular reason you're not just using a Rack-based lightweight web framework to begin with?  Stuff like Sinatra typically have barely any overhead.